# Key AttachDbFilename was not found error when building Lightswitch app

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, database-connection, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've inherited a lightswitch .net app which I'm attempting to build in Visual Studio 2012, (the project was originally built in VS2010 but has been upgraded to VS2012) but am receiving the following error when building (with project build output verbosity set to debug):

```
4>  Task "UpdateDataSourceSection"
4>      Task Parameter:ConfigFile=bin\Debug\\web.config
4>      Task Parameter:Name=_IntrinsicData
4>      Task Parameter:Key=AttachDbFilename
4>      Task Parameter:Value='C:\PathToProject\Bin\Data\ApplicationDatabase.mdf'
4>      Key AttachDbFilename was not found in bin\Debug\\web.config
4>Done building project "Project.lsxproj" -- FAILED.
```

The corresponding part of the web.config file is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectAppDB;User ID=_AppUser;Password=Password;Network Library=dbmssocn" name="_IntrinsicData" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="b30c548d-e3db-4bb5-86a9-e6ae9f716af4" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectAppDB;User ID=_AppUser;Password=Password" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The build error goes away if I add `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf` to the connection string, but I can't see why it's failing in the first place without it.

Answer (score 1):

My memory is a bit sketchy but if i recall correctly the _IntrinsicData connection only works with an internal database (out of the box) and is a nightmare to configure it to work with an external database.

It is possible however to modify the application lsml file to support an external database as seen here: [Change LightSwitch internal database to external](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ad542f8-7169-48b6-8c94-813a61b1e299/can-i-change-the-lightswitch-internal-database-to-an-external-copy)

Alternatively, teams I've worked on have modified the connection strings using post-deployment scripts after publishing the LightSwitch application.  It is possible that the connection string you are using was pulled from a production environment.

To summarise: This isn't an issue for all other External DataSources so in a dev environment we would use a local connection string for the Intrinsic db and modify it after publishing to utilise an external db.

Good luck,
Kris.